# URL Redirect from Catalog Search to Category Page

Tags: category, redirect, catalogsearch, search

Is it possible to redirect from a catalog search to a category page?

For example, from **"*catalogsearch/result/?q=test*"** to **"*test.html*"**? A user would search for the term "test" and would be redirected to the category page of the category called "Test".

I've tried `Catalog->URL Redirects`, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Magento has that ability built in, though it must be managed. If you go to **Catalog -> Search Terms**, you can enter the search query you want to redirect, and the destination URL for the redirect.